# Predict: fork: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: centos, bash, memory-usage

Using many bash parallel processes:

```
process1 &
...
process30 &
```

Doing multiple git operations within each process randomly will produce:

```
 fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

The system is CentOS 7 with no swap, I'd like to be able to wait to spin up the next process until it is safe to. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Like you executed, it will start all the processes in paralell, putting them in the background. That's what the ampersand (`&`) does.

In that case, run the commands in sequence, i. e., one after the other.

To do that, separate each process with a semicolon (`;`) or in new lines, without the final ampersand, like this:

```
process1; process2; ... ; process30
```

or

```
process1
...
process30
```

Like this, it will start process1, and when it ends will start process2, and when process2 ends, it will start process3, and so on, until process30.

If you only want to run the next command if the current one doesn't fail, then separate the commands with two ampersands (`&&`), like this:

```
process1 && process2 && ... && process30
```